# Need examples about injection (1-1) and surjection (onto) of composite functions

Tags: linear-algebra

The task is that I have to come up with examples for the following 2 statements:

> 1/ If the composite $g o f$ is injective (one-to-one), then $f$ is one-to-one, but $g$ doesn't have to be.
>
> 2/ If the composite $g o f$ is surjective (onto), the $g$ is onto, but $f$ doesn't have to be.

I have some difficulties when I try to think of examples, especially the "one-to-one" statement.

** For #1, I try to go about letting the function $f$ being something in the nature of $f(x) = kx$, which is clearly 1-1, and $g$ being something in the nature of $g(x) = x^2$, which is not 1-1.  But then when I try to make g o f out of these two by all of $+, -, x$, and division, it turns out I can't find a 1-1 function $g o f$.

** For #2, I firstly think about letting $f$ being $e^x$, which only covers the positive values of $y$, and then g being something like $k - e^x$.  I thought g o f would cover the whole real line, but when I tries that on matlab, it only covers the negative values of $y$.  So I'm totally wrong >_<

> Little note: I finished the proofs on showing f must be 1-1 (for #1), and g must be onto (for #2).  I just need examples on the "doesn't to be" parts.

Would someone please give me some suggestions ?  I appreciate any help.
Thank you ^_^

Comment: Cause you may have it backwards? for the one-one part doesnt g need to be one-one and f can be anything? and for the onto part if f is onto the g can be one-one or it can be onto since f is onto the one-one function must be onto. for example if f is onto let f|R->R^+ be define by f(x) = x^2 is a onto function but its not one-one so if g is one to one on this function f you have a composition that is one-one when f was not one to one.

Comment: For 1, you want to find an inside function whose range falls into a subset of the domain of the outside function on which the outside function is injective.(and yet outside that subset the outside function is not injective)

Comment: Experiment with square-root functions and for 2, maybe think about the tangent function. You can feed it an interval and get the whole line.

Comment: You've tagged this question as linear-algebra.  Does that mean that you would the functions $f$ and $g$ in your examples to be linear functions between vector spaces?

Comment: @James: Suddenly I thought of the following map: ![Valid XHTML](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/820/75813630.png/). Is my thinking correct?

Comment: @Cecile: That example doesn't quite make sense, but it appears very similar to the answer I had posted an hour earlier.  If you modified it such that $f$ sends $1$ to only one element of the domain of $g$ (because $f(1)$ cannot have more than one value), and such that $g$ sends every element of its domain to $1$ (because $g(x)$ must be defined for all $x$ in the domain of $g$), then it will work.

Comment: Cecile: FYI...since you're fairly new here, when you find an answer that is helpful, you may choose one answer per question to "accept": just click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you want to accept. When you earn just a little more rep, you can upvote as many answers as you'd like to!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider maps $\{0\}\xrightarrow{f}\{0,1\}\xrightarrow{g}\{0\}$, or $\{0\}\xrightarrow{f}A\xrightarrow{g}\{0\}$ where $A$ is any set with more than one element.